# Quick FTP server

Tags: ruby, ftp, rubygems

I'm looking for a quick, configuration-less, FTP server. Something exactly like [Serve](https://github.com/jlong/serve) or [Rack_dav](https://github.com/georgi/rack_dav), but for FTP, which can publish a folder just by running a command.
Is there a gem or something to do such thing?

**Solution**

Based on Wayne's ftpd gem, I created a quick and easy-to-use gem called [Purvey](https://github.com/alfonsocora/purvey).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [ftpd](https://rubygems.org/gems/ftpd) gem supports TLS, and comes with a file system driver.  Like em-ftpd, you supply a driver, but that driver doesn't need to do much.  Here's a bare-minimum FTP server that accepts any username/password, and serves files out of a temporary directory:

```
require 'ftpd'
require 'tmpdir'

class Driver

  def initialize(temp_dir)
    @temp_dir = temp_dir
  end

  def authenticate(user, password)
    true
  end

  def file_system(user)
    Ftpd::DiskFileSystem.new(@temp_dir)
  end

end

Dir.mktmpdir do |temp_dir|
  driver = Driver.new(temp_dir)
  server = Ftpd::FtpServer.new(driver)
  server.start
  puts "Server listening on port #{server.bound_port}"
  gets
end
```

*NOTE*: This example allows an FTP client to upload, delete, rename, etc.

To enable TLS:

```
include Ftpd::InsecureCertificate
...
server.certfile_path = insecure_certfile_path
server.tls = :explicit
server.start
```

*Disclosure*: I am ftpd's author and current maintainer

Comment: Great! I'll use this as the base for a plug-and-play gem. Thanks!

Comment: @alfonso, Please let me know how it works for you.  My email address is in the README.   By the way, I should have mentioned that this example *allows writes/deletes/etc.*.  The next release will have a ReadOnlyDiskFileSystem.

Comment: gem created! It's called [Purvey](https://github.com/alfonsocora/purvey). I also sent you a pull request for a small issue I had when running the specs for ftpd. Feel free to contribute to Purvey if you feel too :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this gem, a Lightweight FTP server framework built on the EventMachine
https://github.com/yob/em-ftpd

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but I need to write a driver in order to use it with a real file system. Do you know if that driver already exists? Sounds like an interest open source project if it doesn't :)

Comment: well, it's not a plug and go gem but you have an example of such a driver on the Git site em-ftpd/examples/fake.rb

Comment: @peter hi, does this LightWeight FTP Server support secure connection? ftps may be?

Comment: don't think so, haven't found any references

Comment: @cypronmaya : Have you figured out any way to do that? i.e support it with FTPS?